# Time series analysis VAR model: AIC and BIC test criteria

Tags: time-series, aic, vector-autoregression, bic

Consider two variables. Imagine you want to analyse the effects of the lags of variable A on variable B. The possiblity you see an effect of variable A on B is reasonable, but there is absolutely no way variable B is predictive of variable A. In this instance, when you construct the VAR model, do you care about AIC and BIC information criteria (since variable B doesn't help predict variable A)? Or would you consider a certain time-frame (for example 6 months or a year)?

Comment: If the effects only go one way (A->B but not B->A) why would you want to run a VAR, which was designed for sets of variables that are all endogenous to each other? Maybe a dynamic time series regression like $B_t = \mu + \alpha_1B_{t-1} + \alpha_2B_{t-2} + ... + \alpha_pB_{t-p} + \beta_0A_t + \beta_1A_{t-1} + ... + \beta_qA_{t-q} + \epsilon_t$ would serve your purpose?

Comment: The traditional way to find out if your reasoning about B not being predictive of A is through a Granger causality test. I do not get how the part about the time frame relates to your question.